# Do I always need to clone an object to ensure encapsulation in Java?

Tags: java, encapsulation

Given an `Outer` class that takes a reference to an object of the `Inner` class as an argument:

```
public class Outer {

    private Inner inner;

    public Outer(Inner inner) {
        // fails
        // this.inner = inner;

        // passes
        this.inner = this.clone(inner);
    }

    public Inner getInner() {
        return this.inner;
    }

    private Inner clone(Inner inner) {
        return new Inner(inner.getInnerValue());
    }
}
```

and the `Inner` class that just has an integer value

```
public class Inner {

    private int innerValue;

    public Inner(int innerValue) { this.innerValue = innerValue; }

    public void setInnerValue(int innerValue) {
        this.innerValue = innerValue;
    }

    public int getInnerValue() {
        return this.innerValue;
    }
}
```

the test

```
class OuterTest {
    @Test
    void testEncapsulation() {
        Inner inner = new Inner(3);
        Outer outer = new Outer(inner);
        inner.setInnerValue(4);
        assertEquals(3, outer.getInner().getInnerValue());
    }
}
```

only passes if I clone `inner` (see comment `fails`). Is this like this in general? So do I need to clone every reference whenever I pass one?

Comment: You can forego cloning if your `Inner` instances are designed to be [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Fun fact: since [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) is not immutable, sonar will produce a warning when you write a setter like this: `public void setDate(final Date date) { this.date = date; }` instead of `public void setDate(final Date date) { this.date = new Date(date.getTime()); }`. Side note: your getter method has the same problem (you leak an internal state to the outside world).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not always.

One other approach for doing is this is to make all setters of `Inner` return a new instance of `Inner`, instead of setting a field of `this`. Usually these setters will have the name " + ", such as `withInnerValue`:

```
public Inner withInnerValue(int innerValue) {
    return new Inner(innerValue);
}
```

And then in the test, you will be forced to do this instead:

```
void testEncapsulation() {
    Inner inner = new Inner(3);
    Outer outer = new Outer(inner);
    inner = inner.withInnerValue(4); <---- this is forced to change
    assertEquals(3, outer.getInner().getInnerValue());
}
```

By rewriting `Inner`'s setters, you have made it *immutable*, that is, its fields can't be changed once an instance has been created.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "Usually these setters will have the name " + ", such as withInnerValue:"? Not sure I'm understanding what you mean here. But interesting approach.. your `withInnerValue` looks almost like my `Outer.clone`.

Comment: @TMOTTM If you look at the classes in the `java.time` package, you see lots of these setters. `LocalDateTime.atOffset`, `LocalDateTime.atZone`, `LocalDateTime.withSecond` etc. The difference from `clone` is that I create a new object when the value is changed, not at the beginning, when it is passed in.

Comment: @TMOTTM  Yes. If you use the cloning approach, you have to remember to clone the object before you return it or pass it somewhere else. But with an immutable object, you are forced to create new objects. If you don't, the compiler would complain.

Comment: So the millions of auto generated setter methods out there are worthless? Or can they just call `withInnerValue(innerValue)` themselves to set the value?

Comment: @TMOTTM Mutable objects have their place too. See [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151733/if-immutable-objects-are-good-why-do-people-keep-creating-mutable-objects) for the counterarguments.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple without clone and etc:

```
class OuterTest {
    @Test
    void testEncapsulation() {
        Inner inner = new Inner(3){{
          setInnerValue(4);
        }};
        Outer outer = new Outer(inner);
        assertEquals(3, outer.getInner().getInnerValue());
    }
}
```